# How to initialize const size array in constructor without explicitly stating the size in class declaration?

Tags: c++, c++98

I need to do something like

```
class foo {
  foo();
  int a[];
}
```

Further in cpp-file:

```
foo::foo() : a{1,2,3,4} {}
```

Peculiarities:

1. C++98 standard
2. array is not int, initializing list is much longer. Though its values are known at compile time, they can change from time to time

EDIT: Another option is also suitable, when `new[]` is used for memory allocation, but, again, it is undesirable to state the array size explicitly:

```
class foo {
  foo();
  int * a;
}
```

Further in cpp-file:

```
foo::foo() {
  a = new[]; // impossible
  // filling the array with values
}
```

Comment: Initialization lists weren't added until C++11

Comment: Either use a class template with the size of the array as a parameter or just use std::vector.

Comment: @Jerfov2 yes, but one can write `int a[] = {1,2,3,4}`, which is exactly what I need except array should be either static or local in this case.

Comment: If you could do what you ask, then what would `sizeof(foo)` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that: The size of the array is part of the *type* of the array, and hence of the class. The constructor is also part of the class. The class needs to exist first *before* you can call constructors, so the constructor *call* cannot influence the class definition.