# std::begin() and std::end() do not work on unknown length array in class

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have array members in a class, whose lengths I don't know (I have C++11 support):

A.h:

```
class A {
    static int array_1[];
    int array_2[];
};
```

A.cpp:

```
int A::array_1[] = {1,2,3};
A::A():array_2{1,2,3} {
    std::sort(std::begin(array_1), std::end(array_1)); // compilation error
    std::sort(std::begin(array_2), std::end(array_2)); // compilation error
}
```

Error message (MSVC): Error C2672   'std::begin': no matching overloaded function

I think both errors are because `array_1` and `array_2` were decayed into pointers. What is the right way I should do to fix the issue and make `std::begin()` and `std::end()` work (I don't know the length of the array when declaring them)?

I thought about using `std::array` but I still have to supply the length in declaration.

Comment: No, the arrays were not decayed into pointers.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Error C2672 'std::begin': no matching overloaded function

Answer (score 1):

The `begin` and `end` function templates only work on complete types. You can simply make the type of `A::array_1` complete in the header file by specifying the size:

```
class A {
    static int array_1[3];
    //                ^^^
};
```

Alternatively, if you are only going to need the complete type in the accompanying source file, just make sure that all uses of the complete type appear *after* the member definition of the static datamember `int A::array_1[] = {1,2,3};`, which completes its type:

```
struct A {
    static int x[];
    A();
};

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int A::x[] = {3, 1, 2};

// Type of A::x is complete at this point.

A::A() {
    for (auto it = std::begin(x); it != std::end(x); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

Note that your class member definition of `array_2` is ill-formed; it *must* be complete in since it is a non-static data member. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43254145) for details.

Comment: I already said I don't know its length when declaring it. And,     uint aa[] = { 1,2,3, 4 };    std::sort(std::begin(aa), std::end(aa)); -- this does work.

Comment: @stanleyli: See update; [full demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L4bwY2CrOTO7laSL).

Comment: "Note that your class member definition of array_2 is ill-formed" - C++11 has the support and I said I am under C++11 environment.

Comment: I didn't see any difference between your code and my `array_1`... Is there any difference?

Comment: @stanleyli: I'm not sure if your code is representative; the key takeaway is to have the correct order and to not have ill-formed constructions. Maybe your compiler is confused by the other errors, try each array in isolation.

Comment: No, C++11 does not allow an array of unknown extent to be a non-static class member.